# Fetch/Axios - Download large static JSON file incomplete data before promise settles

Tags: javascript, fetch, axios

I have large static JSON files hosted on S3 that contain transcripts for video files, and I'm having difficulty loading them using `fetch()` and `Axios`.  The JSON files are anywhere from 50-100KB, and the request seems to settle before the entire file has downloaded - the developer console shows the file arrived with status 200, yet I get errors in the browser:

```
private subtitleUri: string = "https://static.edyoutoo.media/subtitles/167A0DFC566B971A/167A0DFC566B971A-O.json"

// using fetch api
async $fetch(): Promise<SubtitleEntity> {
    const blob = await fetch(this.subtitleUri)
    console.log(blob)
    const json = await blob.json()
    console.log(json)
    return json
}

// using axios
async fetch(): Promise<SubtitleEntity> {
    const ax = Axios.create()
    try {
      const req = await ax.get(this.subtitleUri)
      console.log(req)
      return req.data
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
}
```

The `SubtitleEntity` interface is merely the shape of the JSON object

After attempting, I get this error in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://static.edyoutoo.media/subtitles/167A0DFC566B971A/167A0DFC566B971A-O.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I'm assuming this is because the response settles before the entirety of the data has arrived. **The CORS permissions on the resource is working fine - I used `Postman` to test the request and the data is delivered as expected.**

In the Network tab in Dev Tools, the request shows up with response code 200, and the data is*sometimes* all there, sometimes, it shows this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data when property name was expected at line 855 column 3 of the JSON data
```

Again, I assume this is because of the data transfer is not complete.

What am I doing wrong? I come from a Java/C++ background, and there we simply gather the incoming data into a character buffer in a while loop, and once the request is complete, the data is parsed and returned to the caller.

How is this done with the Axios library or fetch API? And why is it resolving the Future (Promise) before the request has ended?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your very first error message tells you that you don't have permission to retrieve that resource. Yet you mention things like incomplete requests, blah, blah and make no apparent effort to fix the error for which you have a message. :confused: Anyway, have a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: The permissions are OK - I tested this in Postman, and it comes through just fine. All S3 CORS permissions are set properly.

Comment: It's browser's business. Postman does not validate CORS. please read an article. you have to configure backend properly so you would be able to fetch this file in browser with JavaScript

Comment: Nah mate, they're not, really they're not. An XMLHttpRequest made to the url you've provided is rewarded in Chrome with the following message of woe: 

"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://static.edyoutoo.media/subtitles/167A0DFC566B971A/167A0DFC566B971A-O.json with MIME type application/json." Furthermore, if you look at the response-headers for the file, there are only 2 set: `content-type` and `last-modified`. Notice the complete lack of one mentioning origins? That's the problem mate. :)

Comment: I found this was an issue with Cloudfront caching headers - the example file I sent cached the headers without the 'Access-Control' headers, and even after invalidation, it would cache the CORS header for one domain (dev domain) and only that domain. I found any solutions for this to be tedious with Cloudfront, so I decided to go in a different direction.